# How do I restart my loop with get_next_post()?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm looking for a succinct method of making `get_next_post()`

double back to the beginning once it hits the last post.

Currently, it stops once it hits the final post.

Here are a few lines of code from the codex 

for context that are similar to what I'm using:

```
    <?php $next_post = get_next_post();
    if (!empty( $next_post )): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>">
            <?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?>
    </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post

Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: you question isn't really very clear. if you edit your question to be more like what you are ACTUALLY asking I might be able to help.

Comment: @DLaverick I'm using `<?php echo get_permalink( get_post(1) ); ?>` to get a link to my very first post. Is there a succinct method of targeting the ID of my very first post without using a static number?

Comment: is there a reason you are trying to use get_post(); ? seems to me like you could do with a custom query.

Comment: @DLaverick I considered that but It felt convoluted to create a query just to get a post or permalink when `get_post()` and 
`get_next_post()` are succinct and and keeps my code DRY.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do it with get_next_post - full stop.

Here's how I've done it...

```
<?php
/**
* Infinite next and previous post looping in WordPress
*/

$next_post = get_next_post();
$previous_post = get_previous_post();
$current_id = get_the_ID();

// Get ID's of posts
$next_id = $next_post->ID;
$previous_id = $previous_post->ID;
$prev_title = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $previous_post->post_title));
$next_title = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $next_post->post_title));

// get the first posts ID etc
$args = array('post_type'=>'project', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$posts = get_posts($args);
$first_id = $posts[0]->ID;
$first_title = get_the_title( $first_id );


// get the last posts ID etc
$last_post = end($posts);
$last_id =  $last_post->ID; // To get ID of last post in custom post type outside of loop
$last_title = get_the_title( $last_id );

// if the current post isn't the first post
if($current_id != $first_id) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($previous_id) ?>" title="<?php $prev_title ?>" class="prev-next prev">Previous Project:<?php echo $prev_title; ?></a>

<?php    
 // if the current post is the first post
} else { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($last_id) ?>" title="<?php $last_title ?>" class="prev-next prev"> Previous Project</a>
<?php }; ?>

<?php 
// if the current post isn't the last post
if($current_id != $last_id) { ?>
    <a rel="next" href="<?php echo get_permalink($next_id) ?>" title="<?php $next_title ?>" class="prev-next next"> Next Project <?php  echo $next_title; ?></a>

<?php 
// if the current post is the last post
}  else { ?>
    <a rel="next" href="<?php echo get_permalink($first_id) ?>" title="<?php $last_title ?>" class="prev-next next">  Next Project <?php echo $first_title; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Elements take from here [Getting first & last post in custom post type outside of loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037947/getting-first-last-post-in-custom-post-type-outside-of-loop)